# What do we call a person who adapts easily?

Tags: expressions

I know that my mother will be fine after reaching there, she is a person who knows how to adapt very easily.

Comment: Is there some reason “adaptable” won’t work? It seems like a pretty obvious answer.

Comment: "knows how to ... adapt *easily*"  is a little unidiomatic. She adapts easily or knows how to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer is *adaptable*, and adjective for someone who is able to adapt quickly and are good at it. Credit for @mRotten for mentioning this first in the comments.

*Versatile* is also a word, though it doesn't just describe something that can adapt quickly. It can also describe something that has a lot of different things to offer.

A noun that might fit is *chameleon*, though it mostly refers to people who are often change their behavior, beliefs and/or facade, to fit into a situation or please someone at that moment.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adaptable
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/versatile
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chameleon

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion that means a person who "*adapts easily*" is one who is "**flexible**".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/flexible

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing more about your mom and her situation, it's only a guess as to what will fit here:

***Easygoing*** - A person who is usually relaxed and in good humor - even when those around them may not be. Someone who "rolls with the punches". 
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/easy-going

***Resourceful*** - The ability to obtain what you need and want on your own - not necessarily having to depend on others.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resourceful

***Two-faced*** - Able to control one's personality in order to be perceived favorably by conflicting or opposing persons - as well as allies.
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=two%20faced

Comment: That's not what two-faced means.

Comment: @Mitch - Not entirely, but it is an aspect I thought pertained to the question. BTW, great rebuttal.